# Delete file in server fedora 11

Tags: php, fedora

I have an application with server fedora 11. I want to delete 1 object in fedora.This is the code for deleting file:

```
$path = "/opt/html/bancas/scb/csv/test.csv";

if(file_exist($path)){
$delete = exec( "yes | rm /opt/html/bancas/scb/csv/test.csv" );
$delete;
if($delete){
echo "success remove the file";}
else 
{
echo "failed to remove file";
}
}
else
echo "Problem Deleting".$path;
```

But when i check, the file is failed to removed. And there is an meesage "failed to remove file" when i check using firebug.

Please help me

Thanks,
Agung

Comment: you can please check with unlink() function.

Comment: so did you look to see what `$delete` actually contained?

Comment: To delete files, don't use the `exec()` function, this can be very dangerous. Instead make use of `unlink($filepath)`.

Comment: I have trid with unlink. There is an error _Permission denied in <b>/opt/html/bancas/scb/modules/csv_rpt/csv/bersih.php._ This is my code using unlink: $file = "/opt/html/bancas/scb/csv/test.csv";
if(file_exists($file)){
 echo "exist";
 if(unlink($file)){
  echo "successfull deleted";
 }else{
  echo "failed deleted";
 }
}else{
 echo "not exist";
}